# Transformer with reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, transformer-model

I am training a Sequence to Sequence transformer model with RL and both the actor and critic have to be transfomers. But i dont see how i can have one output from the critic when a transformer outputs a sequence rather than just a single scalar reward.

I am using the pretrained t5 from huggingface.

The code for it is here:

https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_t5.html